How to extend the the Ubuntu's computer storage
I have Ubuntu system with the computer storage with 2 GB(not enough). A image shows the storage only has 2 GB
However, I have VMWare Virtual Hard Disk that has 200 GB. Please tell me how use the memory in the VMWare Virtual Hard Disk, or how to extend my computer memory. Thank you.

You are mixing up memory/RAM and disk, your provided picture shows DISK allocation and not memory/RAM, with 1.8GB of available disk capacity/space.  Your question however relates to memory/RAM.

Do you have a separate home folder?
